# user_nicename на кириллице wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите каким образом user_nicename в WordPress можно сделать на русском языке.
По стандартам WordPress если указать такой "ю хевнер" user_nicename то WordPress преобразует в "yu-hevner".

Плагин Wordpress Special Characters in Usernames не работает

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-cyrillic-usernames/

Comment: @SeVlad он не про username, а про nicename. В чистом WP да, нельзя создать юзера с именем Петя: "Error: This username is invalid because it uses illegal characters. Please enter a valid username."

Comment: @KAGGDesign да фиг его знает что имеет ввиду ТС под user_nicename :) Я посмотрел на название плага и решил что именно логины  (username) надо. Именно на эту хотелку Сергей [когда-то и написал этот плаг](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%9a%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5/#post-18430). А нет - так нет.

Answer (score 0):

Отключите плагин транслитерации. Наш cyr2lat не фильтрует nicename - только что проверил.

На чистом WordPress, понятно, такого поведения не может быть в принципе - там нет алгоритмов транслитерации.

Comment: Как раз стоит cyr2lat, деактивировал его и получил как раз urlecode "%d1%8e-%d1%85%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80" и что использовать тогда для транслитерации?

Comment: Ничего не понял, где вы получили urlencode? Ещё раз: последняя версия cyr2lat не конвертирует nicename при задании его на странице админки.